# find holders from same policy but different asset name

Tags: cardano-cli, api, blockfrost

I have a policy ID with hundreds of NFT with different asset name (for eg TTS19, TTS20, etc)

what is the easiest way to find all addresses/wallets which have this NFT(holders)?
I tried with koios and blockfrost but since all nft have a different unique hex asset name I can't show all addresses.

thank you in advanced,
TTS17
theTokenSquare

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Blockfrost you could check for all *"assets of the given policy"* using this endpoint:

```
/assets/policy/{policy_id}
```

*([https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Assets/paths/~1assets~1policy~1{policy_id}/get](https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Assets/paths/%7E1assets%7E1policy%7E1%7Bpolicy_id%7D/get))*

and then for each asset you can get the holder through this endpoint:

```
/assets/{asset}/addresses
```

*([https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Assets/paths/~1assets~1{asset}~1addresses/get](https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Assets/paths/%7E1assets%7E1%7Basset%7D%7E1addresses/get))*

Comment: thank you mate, that was the combination of requests i had on my mind and understanding.  - we were looking for direct only one request for only one policy for all the assets once.

Answer (score 2):

A of time of posting available services of `blockfrost` and `koios` require you to query combination of multiple endpoints. So therefore for more advanced/specific usage you probably best of querying `cardano-db-sync` instance your self.

As example you take a look at [asset_address_list.sql](https://github.com/cardano-community/guild-operators/blob/master/files/grest/rpc/assets/asset_address_list.sql) at [github.com/cardano-community/guild-operators](https://github.com/cardano-community/guild-operators) repo how to build your query.